# Preventing scaling during raster rendering in MapServer

Tags: raster, openlayers, mapserver

I have encoded some metrics in a 4-band geotiff that will be served by MapServer (v7.4), and I want to "decode" them client-side for display using raster operations in OpenLayers (v6.1). (This is something somewhat similar to what is done in this [openlayers workshop](https://openlayers.org/workshop/en/raster/raster.html).)

The problem is that my metrics values range from 1 to 156 (and I used 255 for nodata), and MapServer scale them to 0-254 during rendering for better display, so the client do not have access to the original metrics.

I would need the client to have access to the original values. I have tried adding the following directives to the mapfile layer definition, but to no avail.
'PROCESSING "LUT=1:1,156:156"'
or 'PROCESSING "SCALE=0,254"'

Here is the layer definition:

```
LAYER
    NAME tif_source
    STATUS ON
    TYPE RASTER
    DATA "/test.tif"
    PROJECTION
        "init=epsg:32198"
    END

    METADATA
        wms_enable_request "*"
        wms_title "tif_source"
    END

    # PROCESSING "SCALE_1=0,254"  ## does not produce the expected result
    # PROCESSING "LUT=1:1,156:156" ## does not work either
    PROCESSING "LOAD_FULL_RES_IMAGE=YES"

    DEBUG 4
END
```

How should I prevent MapServer from scaling the raster values during rendering?

Comment: No automatic scaling should happen. What is your outputformat and do you have special settings for that format? How do you exactly handle 4-band input? Do you select the three bands for RGB with processing directive?

Comment: Make sure it is not a client issue.  Be sure to set `context.imageSmoothingEnabled = false` as in https://openlayers.org/en/main/examples/sea-level.html

Comment: No special directive for the format, png (AGG/PNG) is used with its default values. 
No special directive either for the bands, they seem to be picked correctly. From the debug logs: "msDrawRasterLayerGDAL(): red,green,blue,alpha bands = 1,2,3,4"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use data from a W*S then you should be using a WCS not a WMS. a WMS returns a **picture** of the data while a WCS returns the actual raster data.

MapServer supports [WCS](https://www.mapserver.org/ogc/wcs_server.html) so it should be easy.

Comment: That is true, but if input images are 8-bit with one or three bands it should possible, if not the default, to keep pixel values unchanged. Despite the effect of resampling, naturally.

Comment: No guarantee of any thing in a WMS just don't do it